# JQuery parseerror on <anonymous>

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

Getting json from a php object. Testing it solo, the PHP returns properly formed json, and no indication of . I have searched the web for suggestions, and reviewed the documentation, but not finding a solution.

Thank you!

In the console, getting the following error:

```
parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at jQuery.parseJSON (jquery-1.11.2.js:8515)
    at ajaxConvert (jquery-1.11.2.js:8841)
    at done (jquery-1.11.2.js:9259)
    at XMLHttpRequest.callback (jquery-1.11.2.js:9713)
```

Code snippet:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#submit').click(function(){
            alert('Loading data...');
            $.ajax({
                 url: "jsonData.php",
                 type: "GET",
                 data: {},
                 dataType: "json",
                 success: function(data) {
                      alert('Presenting data...');
                      $("#result").html(data);
                  },
                 error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                  console.log(textStatus,errorThrown);
                 }
         });
     });
});
</script>
```

Result is a simple div

```
   <div id="result" class="well"></div>
```

json:

```
{"data":[{"key":"1002","sc":"3214","date":"15-Dec-2016 10:15 AM"},{"key":"1003","sc":3215"","date":"15-Dec-2016 10:17 AM"}]}
```

Comment: **data: {}** ? if you do not have data to post than why you use data attribute ?

Comment: Remnant from my trying other options. Dropping or adding makes no difference to the error

Comment: have you got the same json response ? from PHP side?

Comment: I suggest to check your response correctly, maybe there is an HTML tag in your response and this tag will occur parsing error.

Comment: Thank Soni.  Discovered the manual json I was using had a syntax error. On the generated json , once I captured *all* the data coming back, had  missed HTML in the beginning. This was causing the parseerror.  Now I've successful loaded data from my php data object.

Comment: That's great njoy coding.... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is not valid.

```
{"key":"1003","sc":3215"","date":"15-Dec-2016 10:17 AM"}
```

`"sc":3215""` should be `"sc":"3215"`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your Json Response **(Invalid)**

```
{
    "data": [{
        "key": "1002",
        "sc": "3214",
        "date": "15-Dec-2016 10:15 AM"
    }, {
        "key": "1003",
        "sc": 3215 "",
        "date": "15-Dec-2016 10:17 AM"
    }]
}
```

> "sc": 3215 "", **not proper**

It should be like this

```
{
    "data": [{
        "key": "1002",
        "sc": "3214",
        "date": "15-Dec-2016 10:15 AM"
    }, {
        "key": "1003",
        "sc": "3215",
        "date": "15-Dec-2016 10:17 AM"
    }]
}
```

> "sc": "3215", is should like this